# Median across multiple axes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
cid        1   1       1      2      2     3   3
slot                                            
87     26.45 NaN   12.54    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN
88       NaN NaN     NaN   8.12    NaN   NaN NaN
89    108.72 NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN NaN
90      9.56 NaN  110.42  58.95  15.17  32.9 NaN
```

I'd like to calculate the median of all identically named columns across both index and columns, ideally getting a series:

```
1    26.45
2    15.17
3    32.90
Name: cid, dtype: float64
```

Getting the median across one of these dimensions is trivial, but I can't seem to get it across both (and doing one and then the other is not the same thing).

I've tried melt and index shenanigans, but I always seem to end up with the median long just one axis.

I'm sure the solution is painfully obvious, but I can't seem to see through the haze of Monday morning.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like:

```
>>> pd.melt(df).groupby("cid")["value"].median()
cid
1      26.45
2      15.17
3      32.90
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Splendid!  I thought melt was the key, but I neglected the ["value"].

Comment: @offbyone: even without `['value']` it'd work, it'd just give you a `DataFrame` with `value` as the name of the column.